# CodeFirst EF and connection string by Adam's Freeman book

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, ef-code-first, connection-string

I'm learning the asp.net mvc 3 of the book of Adam Freeman. In the example, a SportsStore applications using CodeFirst approach. When solution run throws exception: **Invalid object name 'dbo.Products'.**
I'm assuming that the problem in the connection string. My *Web.config* expample:

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="EFDbContext" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=SportsStore;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

and csharp code:

```
public class EFProductRepository : IProductRepository
{
    private EFDbContext context = new EFDbContext();

    public IQueryable<Product> Products
    {
        get
        {
            return context.Products;
        }
    }
}

public class EFDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
}
```

add code to *Global.asax* file Application_Start() method:

```
ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(new NinjectControllerFactory());
```

my Controller:

```
 public class ProductController : Controller
{
    private IProductRepository repository;

    public ProductController(IProductRepository repoParam)
    {
        repository = repoParam;
    }

    public ViewResult List()
    {
        var products = repository.Products.ToList();
        return View(products.AsQueryable());
    }
}
```

exception throws when I'm cast products ToList()

I downloaded an archive with code examples for this book. Changed *web.config*. When launched, this solution is an exception generated too
Anybody know what the problem?
Thanks!

Comment: Can you show the bit of code around where the error occurs? Specifically how you are instantiating "dbo"?

Comment: Have you created the db's and tables?

Comment: Yes of course. I created db and one table *Product* and fill it. In Server Explorer added new connection to this db. Check test connection. All correctly working.

Comment: As the exception states the table should named **Products** not Product, note the `s` at the end.

Comment: You were right. I renamed table. all working)